# Creating a new svn checkout by copying an svn versioned subfolder

Tags: svn, export, svn-checkout

My problem is that I would like to make a copy of a subfolder of a checkout which will be a new checkout, but without connecting to the repository.

Previously I'd used svn 1.6. There, one needs just to copy any folder because each folder has a `.svn` directory. In svn 1.8, now the `.svn` directory is only at the top level, so plain copying does not work anymore.

Is there a way to create a new checkout of a subfolder of an existing checkout without needing a connection to the repository?

Clarification:
1) I have checkout in 1.8; 2) I want to create a subfolder checkout, e.g. on another drive; 3) to do this without connecting to repository, no add, no update, no checkin. It was simple to do in 1.6 by just copying the folder to another place, but seems unclear how to do it in 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood your question, but i guess what you want is moving from a 1.6 svn repository to another repository which is in 1.8.

You could do as follow

- export from 1.6 in `<folder1>`
- checkout from 1.8 in `<folder2>`
- Copy what you need in `<folder1>` into `<folder2>`
- from your `<folder2>` use `svn add` to add what you need to the repository
- then commit the changes

When you are using checkout, you get all the .svn folder which are useful for svn to keep track of versions. 
But, if you don't want the .svn folders, then you can use the `svn export` command.

Comment: No. 1) I have checkout in 1.8; 2) I want to create a subfolder checkout, e.g. on another drive; 3) to do this without connecting to repository, no add, no update, no checkin.
It was simple to do in 1.6 by just copying the folder to another place, but seems unclear how to do it in 1.8.

Comment: Your .svn folder will be at the root directory of your checkout. If you want to keep it in your subfolder you could simply checkout this subfolder

Comment: This is the problem. I want to get a new subfolder WITHOUT checkout. In 1.6 I could do this by simply copying the subfolder at a new location (because in 1.6 each subfolder had .svn directory).

Comment: I'm not sure i understand why you would need to do that. 
I think you were using a behavior which was not intended. Maybe if you explain why, we could figure out a better solution.

Though, you could work with two working-copy (with two checkout of the same revision) and then use one as a 'save' for the subfolder, but again, this is not really the 'svn' way.

Comment: Suppose that in that particular subfolder I have 2Gb amount of data. My svn server is slow and the traffic is limited. Hence instead of checkout new 2Gb I need just to copy locally, as I used to do it in 1.6.